# iPod: How to fire clickwheel events?

Tags: ios, event-handling, ipod

I'd like to develop a simple tool for controlling the clickwheel of an connected Apple iPod. The development should be easy but I've no idea how to start. A solution like that would be great:

```
# Pseudocode
$iPod = new iPodFramework()->getConnectedDevices()->select(0);
$iPod->play();
```

I just need to fire these events by clicking buttons:

- Menu
- Prev
- Forward
- Play/Pause
- Middle-Button
- Scroll up/down
- Hold on/off

There are several remote controls in the stores which actually do the same, but how? I don't want to spam, so I avoid posting a link for now.

Does anyone know...

- how to start?
- which language I need?
- any tutorials, frameworks, code-snippets?
- keywords/topics for googling?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not certain that this is possible over USB. There are several special-purpose communication lines in the iPod dock connector that are used by the remote controls you've seen to issue commands; these are not part of USB, and as such are not exposed to the host.

Comment: @duskwuff Thanks for your reply! My hope is: the (USB-) remote controls have to send any data to the iPod via USB. There must be a way to emulate/simulate that my PC is a remote control. But unfortunately I've no idea, how.